# Do I need a constructor with Inheritance?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

I have the following to classes(*POCO's?*) where the second is supposed to extend the first.

I am guessing I need a property referencing the base instance, Business in this case, but do I also need a Constructor to "fill" that property since an Insurance Company can't exist without a Business?

My reference for this is the underlying DB where `tblInsuranceCompany` has a FK constraint on column `BusinessID` back to `tblBusiness`.

Additionally, I am very new at OOP so please point out anything else you may see "wrong".  Thanks,

```
public class Business
{
    public int BusinessID { get; set; }

    public BusinessType BusinessType { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public DateTime? InactiveDate { get; set; }

    public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public IList<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    public string DisplayString { get { return this.ToString(); } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}: {1}", Name, BusinessType.TypeDescription);
    }
}

public class InsuranceCompany : Business
{
    public int InsuranceCompanyID { get; set; }

    public Business Business { get; set; }

    public InsuranceCompanyType InsuranceCompanyType { get; set; }

    public string DRIInsuranceCompanyNumber { get; set; }

    public string DisplayString { get { return this.ToString(); } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}: {1}", Business.Name, InsuranceCompanyType.TypeDescription);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `InsuranceCompany` "is-a" `Business` or "has-a" `Business`? You're doing both, which is wrong.

Comment: @SLaks: So the Inheritance (`:Business`) defines a "is-a" but the property `public Business Business` defines a "has-a"?  If that's correct then thank you for clarifying that for me.  I knew the difference between the 2 I have just never had it applied to "work code" if you know what I mean.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am guessing I need a property referencing the base instance, Business in this case,

No, you don't need this.  The InsuranceCompany **is** the business.  It will also have all of the properties of `Business` since it inherits from `Business`.  You don't need a property to reference this, as the reference to the `InsuranceCompany` object will be the same reference as the reference to the "business" portion (they're the same object).

> but do I also need a Constructor to "fill" that property since an Insurance Company can't exist without a Business?

All classes get a constructor - When you construct an InsuranceCompany, it will effectively construct the "business" as well.

That being said, you may want a constructor that passes the relevant information to the base class constructor - but if you don't provide one, the compiler will create a default constructor for you.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but leads to another question, If I add a Constructor that means this is no longer a POCO, correct?  I should have another class then or am I confusing the two.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin You can have a constructor and still be a POCO - though it's typically nice to have a default constructor in addition to any that take arguments, depending on teh usage scenario...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, if you are confusing inheritance with composition here.

If InsuranceCompany is a type of business, then inheritance would be a possible solution. In this case you don't need a Business property, the object itself is a business and has all the properties thereof. The InsuranceCompany and Business are not two different instances, they are one.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `Name` property (or `base.Name`) in InsuranceCompany and remove the Business property from the derived class.